# Is there any way to update browser cache instead of clearting it.?

Tags: php, browser-cache

In one of my projects am working on improvement of page speed.

I used .htaccess file to enable browser cache. Below is the piece of the code.

```
# 1 YEAR = 29030400
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK = 604800
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 DAYS = 172800
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

 # 1 MIN = 60
 <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate, must-revalidate"
  </FilesMatch>
```

Problem with this code is code when ever new data is added that data is not reflecting in page.

Is there any way to update the cache when ever new data is insrted into DB.

Comment: No, there isn't. That is against the idea of a cache. Caching something means you save all effort to check if things have changed for a given period of time, trusting that it is ok to do so. That is what the cache control is for. Caching and _still_ checking if things have changed makes no sense. It would mean to _still_ having to invest the effort.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to add a count parameter to your URLs, e.g.

```
http://mysite.mydomain.com/test.ico?count=1
```

The count parameter will be ignored by the web server but it will be stored in the browser cache. Update the count value whenever you change the image and it will be re-loaded. You can even use a date/timestamp (with the file creation date) and automate the entire thing.